# How do I delete a button in python using tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to delete/hide the flashlight button if I later designate flashlight_show to "hide". But Im not sure how to do it. I have been looking around and just can't find an answer.

```
healthKit_show = "show"
flashlight_show = "show"
def supplies_buttons():
    supplies_showing = 1
    flashlight_var = Button(Supplies, text = "Flashlight", command=flashlight)
    healthKit_var =  Button(Supplies, text = "healthKit", command=healthKit)
    if flashlight_show == "show":
        flashlight_var.grid(row=supplies_showing, column=0, sticky=W)
        supplies_showing = supplies_showing + 1
    if not flashlight_show == "show":
        flashlight_var.pack_forget()
    if healthKit_show == "show":
        healthKit_var.grid(row=supplies_showing, column=0, sticky=W)
        supplies_showing = supplies_showing + 1
    if not flashlight_show == "show":
        healthKit_var.pack_forget()
supplies_buttons()
flashlight_show = "hide"
supplies_buttons()
```

Comment: Since you're using the `grid` layout manager, you should call the widget's `grid_forget()` method to remove it from the manager — `pack_forget()` doesn't do anything in this situation since you're not using the `pack` layout manager to display any of the widgets you have.

Comment: Your logic is broken. Recreating widgets at the same place leads to stacking widgets which is not usefull at all.